# Plotly set color

Tags: javascript, plotly

I feel like ive tried everything but nothing seem to work:

```
            var charData = [{
                    x: x1,
                    y: y,
                    type: 'bar',
                    color: 'rgb(31,119,180)',
                    orientation: 'h',
                    name: 'Nuværende',
                    bar: {
                        color: 'rgb(rgb(31, 114, 225)'
                    }
                }, {
                    x: x2,
                    y: y,
                    type: 'bar',
                    orientation: 'h',
                    name: 'Forventet'
                }],
                layout = {
                    title: 'Brugere',
                    barmode: 'stack',
                    legend: {
                        orientation: 'h'

                    }
                };
            Plotly.newPlot(area,charData,layout);
```

Ive also tried:

```
            var charData = [{
                    x: x1,
                    y: y,
                    type: 'bar',
                    color: 'rgb(31,119,180)',
                    orientation: 'h',
                    name: 'Nuværende',
                    color: '#23b7e5'
                }, {
                    x: x2,
                    y: y,
                    type: 'bar',
                    orientation: 'h',
                    name: 'Forventet'
                }],
                layout = {
                    title: 'Brugere',
                    barmode: 'stack',
                    legend: {
                        orientation: 'h'

                    }
                };
            Plotly.newPlot(area,charData,layout);
```

However the chart stays with default colors.

So how can i change colors using `Plotly?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
var charData = [{
                x: x1,
                y: y,
                type: 'bar',
                orientation: 'h',
                name: 'Nuværende',
                marker: {
                  color: '#23b7e5'
                }
            }],
            layout = {
                title: 'Brugere',
                barmode: 'stack',
                legend: {
                    orientation: 'h'

                }
            };
        Plotly.newPlot(area,charData,layout);
```

Another example [here](https://plot.ly/javascript/bar-charts/#bar-chart-with-hover-text).